# logout/login from inside Vagrantfile

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm currently trying to finish a Vagrantfile to be used as a docker host by other Vagrantfiles running the docker provider (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/).

I am using `centos/atomic-host` as a base box. The problem is that when I run `vagrant up` I get:

> A Docker command executed by Vagrant didn't complete successfully!
>   The command run along with the output from the command is shown
>   below.
>
> Command: "docker" "ps" "-a" "-q" "--no-trunc"
>
> Stderr: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

And this is due to the vagrant user not being part of the docker group. I solve this by adding this to my Vagrantfile:

```
# Add user vagrant to docker group
$docker_group = <<-DOCKER_GROUP
    groupadd docker
    usermod -a -G docker vagrant
    systemctl restart docker
DOCKER_GROUP
config.vm.provision "docker_group", type: "shell", privileged: true, inline: $docker_group
```

I still get the exception above the first time I run vagrant up but it works from the second time onwards. The reason I suspect is that after adding the vagrant user to the docker group I need to logout/login for the changes to take effect.

For the record, I tried adding `newgrp docker` at the end of the my `$docker_group` script but it doesn't solve the problem. I suspect the docker provider starts a separate session.

Anybody found a solution for this?

Comment: The error that you are getting is usually received when the docker daemon is not running.. have you checked if docker is running or not?

Comment: It is, as I said, I suspect the problem is that, after adding the vagrant user to the docker group, we need a logout/login for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of Vagrantfile, but what I understand from your question is that you need some way to refresh a user's group without having to re-login.

If that's the case, the following points may help you:

1. Why not just su to the user again: you may just login in to the user again, and all the user's group will be updated.
2. Or you may try the [this](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out) approach Legooolas has mentiones.

I hardly think the problem you mentioned is with the Vagrantfile, it's just the way it is. To update user's configurations, you need to re-login with the user. Still, if you wish to find a way, the above two might help you out.